# Large scope regex for quantity and prices in finance

Tags: python, regex, price, product-quantity

I am doing some data mining on a huge quantity of financial data and I need to find out two python regex that match:

Prices, such as:

```
16 666 666.67
16 666 666,67
666 666.67
5 567.1
5 677,1
0.0
0,101
5,4
5.40
54.0
5.675674754747457
5980990.009345
16,000.45
234,234,657.108
```

There is always a coma or a dot in the price. But there could be spaces before the coma (spaces need to be consistent, not like `56 34.345` for instance)

Volume (quantity), such as:

```
9898
5
450934
5,000
1,000
1,000,000
5,998
11
0
5 000
1 000 000
1 980 000 000
599
233 590
23 613
181 876 980
```

Quantity is never dot separated. It cannot have decimals basically.

Here is the one I tried for prices:
`(^[0-9]{0,}$)|(\d{1,}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d*))`
But I fail to handle spaces.

And for the volume, it is very complicated to me since there are also spaces everywhere !

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your "desired" output?

Comment: Is there some context around these numbers in the string from which you are trying to match the expression or do you get the numbers just like in your examples? If there's more stuff around, then this would be nice to know to help.

Comment: @FailSafe A boolean is ok, the entire volume or quantity captured is better, as you can !

Comment: @TheKvist There could be `(`or things glued around, yes

Comment: In the prices, are some of the commas decimal separators and some of them digit separators?

Comment: For example is `0,1` the same as `0.1`, but `1,000.0` is different from `1,000`?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso No coma decimal separator

Comment: so `0,101` is the same as `101`?

Comment: @CoffeeTableExpresso `1,000.0`and `1,000` are identical

Comment: So let me see if I understand. You want to match things like `666 666.67` and `5 567.1` but you DON'T want it to match `56 34.345`. What exactly is the difference you are looking to exclude in these examples?

Comment: @CoffeTableEspresso `0,101` should not be possible for quantity. I will update my post, quantity should be alway Positive and Natural

Comment: @FailSafe `56 34.345` not correct, correct is `5 634.345`

Comment: Where can commas appear in prices? I thought initially you had the same restriction on them as spaces, but you have examples such as `5,4`.

Comment: @FailSafe Sorry I don't very get it. Its a price basically, it can have decimals and formats are different (european, american), so sometime thousands are coma separated, sometimes space separated, if thousands are dot separated then there should be no coma (otherwise does not make sense)

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso `5,4` is ok, `5.4` is ok, `5,4.5` is not ok, `5,400.5`is ok

Comment: by `dot separated` do you mean `has a decimal place`?

Comment: Is `5,4` the same as `5.4` (just written differently)?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Yes, exactly !

Comment: @zakk8889 hopefully my answer helps, let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a bit more than just regex in this case.

First, normalizing each line is good, since there's lots of acceptable formats. We'll normalize so that `.` is always the decimal separator and  is always the thousand separator:

```
if '.' not in line:
    # `,` is our separator, so replace with `.`
    line = line.replace(',', '.')
else:
    # `.` is our separator, so replace `,` with ` ` (does nothing if already space separated).
    line = line.replace(',', ' ')
```

Now, we can apply the regex to `line`:

`^\d{1,3}(\s\d{3})*\.\d+$` will match anything with the thousands separated.
`^\d+\.\d+$` will match anything without the thousands separated.

Note that since we did a little pre-processing on the lines, our regex is waaaaay simpler. I'll leave the quantity one (should be easier) and capturing the appropriate pieces to you.

I'd also recommend capturing the whole string, and then calling `.replace(' ', '')` on it to strip out spaces, rather than trying to strip them out inside the regex.

Comment: I will use the method you suggested and try come back with a nice function. Thanks

Comment: sure, let me know if it works (and if it does, please accept this answer).

Comment: sure, give me some time to try it out !